# How to get with loop in array

Tags: php

When I use :

```
foreach ($pages['data'] as $page) {
    $page_access_token = $page['access_token'];
    $page_conversations = $facebook->api('/222222222222/conversations', 'GET', array('access_token' => $page_access_token)); 

    $SenderName = $page_conversations["data"][0]["participants"]["data"][0]["name"];
    $IDPage     = $page_conversations["data"][0]["participants"]["data"][0]["id"];

    echo $SenderName;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $IDPage;
}
```

I only get index[0] from my data.

```
Anti Virus Indonesia
171360273518
```

How to loop all data like :

```
Anti Virus Indonesia
171360273518
TelkomVision Interact
1413864677
```

How do I get the data from the data like this?

Comment: You haven't pasted the link to your data correctly.

Comment: Can you paste the data in pastebin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its almost like aiming blind folded without the data. But can you try this once?

```
foreach ($pages['data'] as $page) {
    $page_access_token = $page['access_token'];
    $page_conversations = $facebook->api('/222222222222/conversations', 'GET', array('access_token' => $page_access_token)); 

    foreach ($page_conversations["data"] as $conversations) {
        $SenderName = $conversations["participants"]["data"][0]["name"];
        $IDPage     = $conversations["participants"]["data"][0]["id"];
        echo $SenderName;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $IDPage;
    }

}
```

Or this one

```
foreach ($pages['data'] as $page) {
    $page_access_token = $page['access_token'];
    $page_conversations = $facebook->api('/222222222222/conversations', 'GET', array('access_token' => $page_access_token)); 

    foreach ($page_conversations["data"][0]["participants"]["data"] as $conversations) {
        $SenderName = $conversations["name"];
        $IDPage     = $conversations["id"];
        echo $SenderName;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $IDPage;
    }

}
```